# Sum Values in One Range Based on Criteria in Another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple spreadsheet, two columns "Amount" (col Q) and "Account" (col O).  I want to get the sum of the "Amount" column where the corresponding "Account" forum equals "Paypal".

This is as far as I can get!

```
=SUM(Q:Q)*(O:O="Paypal")
```

Comment: Your above formula would would if you wrote it this way:  
`=SUM(Q:Q*(O:O="Paypal"))`, and committed it using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: That works but it will be super-slow compared with `SUMIF`. Array formulae seem to work on the whole column (down to row 1048576), so if you need to use them, it's best to use a more limited range (e.g. `Q2:Q2000`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe rather than using `SUM()` you want the `SUMIF()` function.  I don't have Excel to hand but I believe you need your formula to be

```
=SUMIF(O:O,"Paypal",Q:Q)
```

From [this site](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php)

> The syntax for the SumIf function is:
>
> ```
> SumIf( range, criteria, sumRange )
> ```
>
> *range* is the range of cells that you want to apply the criteria
>   against. (your column containing "Paypal"
>
> *criteria* is used to determine which cells to add. - In your case matching "paypal"
>
> *sumRange* are the cells to sum.

Also see [this Microsoft help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx), and this  page which has some [more advanced functions](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/sum-if.htm) such as DSUM and SUMPRODUCT.